# Cyclic Composition Operators on Hardy Space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

Let $H^2$ denote the [Hardy space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_space#Hardy_spaces_for_the_unit_disk) on the complex disk $D\subseteq \mathbb{C}$.  Recall that for a function $f:D\rightarrow D$ the associated composition operator $C_f$ is defined by
$$
\begin{aligned}
C_f:H^2 &\rightarrow H^2\\
g &\mapsto g\circ f.
\end{aligned}
$$
We recall that $C_f$ is call [cylic](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Cyclic_vector) if there is some $g^f\in H^2$ such that $\operatorname{span}\{g^f\circ f^n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is dense in $H^2$.
Lastly, let $L(H^2)$ denote the space of bounded linear operators on $H^2$ with the [weak operator topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_operator_topology).

Is the set of composition operators $C_f$ for which $f$ is cylic, dense in $L(H^2)$?  If yes, what about if it instead has the strong operator topology?